# String Object Not Callable When Using Tuples and Ints

Tags: python

I am utterly flustered. I've created a list of tuples from a text file and done all of the conversions to ints:

```
for line in f:
    if firstLine is True: #first line of file is the total knapsack size and # of items. 
        knapsackSize, nItems = line.split()
        firstLine = False 
    else:
        itemSize, itemValue = line.split()
        items.append((int(itemSize), int(itemValue)))
print items

knapsackSize, nItems = int(knapsackSize), int(nItems) #convert strings to ints
```

I have functions that access the tuples for more readable code:

```
def itemSize(item): return item[0]
def itemValue(item): return item[1]
```

Yet when I call these functions, i.e.,:

```
elif itemSize(items[nItems-1]) > sizeLimit
```

I get an inexplicable `"'str' object is not callable"` error, referencing the foregoing line of code. I have type checked everything that should be a tuple or an int using instsanceof, and it all checks out. What gives?

Comment: `itemSize, itemValue = line.split()` means `itemSize` is a `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because at this point:

```
itemSize, itemValue = line.split()
```

`itemSize` is still a string - you've appended to `items` the `int` converted values...

I would also change your logic slightly for handling first line:

```
with open('file') as fin:
    knapsackSize, nItems = next(fin).split() # take first line
    for other_lines in fin: # everything after
        pass # do stuff for rest of file
```

Or just change the whole lot (assuming it's a 2column file of ints)

```
with open('file') as fin:
    lines = (map(int, line.split()) for line in fin)
    knapsackSize, nItems = next(lines)
    items = list(lines)
```

And possibly instead of your functions to return items - use a `dict` or a `namedtuple`...

Or if you want to stay with functions, then go to the `operator` module and use:

```
itemSize = operator.itemgetter(0)
```